# NullException with INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to make a battleship game in WPF C# and whenever I click on a cell within the Border to fire at the enemy ship I get a nullreferenceexception within my INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
    class BattleshipVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        string time = "";
        public CellModel[][] OurMap {get; private set;}
        public CellModel[][] EnemyMap { get; private set; }


        public string Time
        {
            get => time;
private set => Set(ref time, value);
        }
        DispatcherTimer timer;
        DateTime startTime;
        string ourMap =
            @"**********
              XXXX**X**X
              ******X***
              X*******X*
              X*********
              X****XX***
              ***X******
              ******X***
              *******X**
              ***X****X*
              **********


";


        string enemyMap =
            @"*X******X*
              *******X**
              **XX******
              X*****X***
              **********
              *XXX***X**
              **********
              *X***XXX**
              **X*******
              ***X***XX*
              ****X*****


";
        public BattleshipVM()
        {
       
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            OurMap = MapFabric(ourMap);
            EnemyMap = MapFabric(enemyMap);
           
        }
        CellModel[][] MapFabric(string str)
        {
            var mp = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var map = new CellModel[10][];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                map[i] = new CellModel[10];
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    map[i][j] = new CellModel(mp[i][j]);
                }
            }
            return map;
        }

        internal void ShotToOurMap(int X, int Y)
        {
            OurMap[X][Y].SetState();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var dt = now - startTime;
            Time = dt.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            timer.Start();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    public class CellModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        Visibility visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        bool ship;

        public CellModel(char state)
        {
            ship = state == 'X';
        }

        public Visibility Miss { get => visibility; private set => Set(ref visibility, value); }
        public void SetMiss()
        {
            Miss = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public Visibility Shot { get => visibility; private set => Set(ref visibility, value); }
        public void SetState()
        {
            if (ship)
                
                Shot = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                Miss = Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }
}
```

and this is the mainwindow xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CellModel}">
        <Border BorderBrush="DarkSalmon"
                                        Width="30" Height="30" 
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        Margin="0,0,-1,-1"
                                        MouseDown="Border_MouseDown"
                                        Background="NavajoWhite">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Width="7" Height="7"
                                                 Fill="Tomato"
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                 Visibility="{Binding Miss}">
                </Ellipse>
                <Path 
                                              Stroke="#8F00" Data="M4,4L25,25M25,4L4, 25" StrokeThickness="3"
                                              Visibility="{Binding Shot}"></Path>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="36"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                      x:Name="TimeShow">
            0:00 </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Steps}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" > Step: 5:
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Goal}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" > Goal 3:
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content=" Start " Grid.Column="1" Click="btnStart"/>
        <Button Content=" Stop " Grid.Column="2" Click="btnStop"/>
        <ItemsControl 
          Grid.Column="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding OurMap}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl 
          Grid.Column="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding EnemyMap}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                </StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

This is the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Battleship
{
    internal class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       
        protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            if (!field.Equals(value))
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }


        }
        protected void Fire(params string[] names)
        {
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the main window cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Battleship
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        BattleshipVM bs = new BattleshipVM();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = bs;
            bs = new BattleshipVM();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            bs.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bs.Stop();
        }

        private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           
            var bor = sender as Border;
            var cellModel = bor.DataContext as CellModel;

            cellModel.SetState();
            var X = rnd.Next(10);
            var Y = rnd.Next(10);

            bs.ShotToOurMap(X, Y);


        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the Data Template into Windows.Resources so it would be available to the entire program and made the DataTemplates DataType as the local class CellModel that is the one that makes the hits and misses visible when the player hit but this is all to not avail. Been at it for three days with this error and still cannot figure it out.

Comment: "whenever I click on a cell within the Border to fire at the enemy ship I get a nullreferenceexception within my INotifyPropertyChanged" - it is just funny because there are no clicks or INotifyPropertyChanged anywhere in the code you showed

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it and added the INotifyPropertyChanged the clicks are on the MouseDown section

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] you'll get better answers. At a minimum show us the line of code that threw the exception.